# I'm making an ASCII rpg in c++ where my character moves using arrow keys. How do i make my character the unicode smiley?

Tags: c++, ascii

I am using the '@' symbol to act as my character right now. I want to switch it to the unicode ☺ smiley.      Below is an example of an ASCII map where my character (currently '@') starts at the top left. The code works by when i hit the arrow keys, the map clears my '@' character symbol and creates it in the adjacent spot in the chosen direction. Basically, instead of my character being a '@' i want it to be a '☺'

```
char map[10][23] = {
"##########   #########",
"#@       #   #       #",
"#        #   #####   #",
"#        #       #   #",
"#        #########   #",
"#                    #",
"######################" };
```

Comment: You should go all in on unicode then. `wchar_t`, `wcout`, the whole works.

Comment: Step 1: Ask your user to use a terminal that supports UTF-8. Step 2: Use `u8"☺"`.

Comment: @user4581301 Be careful, `wchar_t` is not a fixed-size character type, it's implementation (compiler) specific. On Windows using MSVC++ `wchar_t` is 16 bits and represents an UTF-16 encoded code-point. Better use a fixed-width like `char32_t` internally, which can represent the full Unicode space, and then output using UTF-8 (if the terminal can handle it).

Comment: Thanks for the help all